Gaps at Top of Shower Wall Corners
we noticed that there are gaps at the top of the corners where the shower wall ceramic tiles and metal trim meet. Pictures in the link below. What would be the best way to try to cover these gaps to avoid water or humidity from going in there? It’s not noticeable but still worried about it. (Never noticed it until now after living several years at this house).

EDIT: Thanks all! Very helpful. Is there a particular connector piece that should be used at corners like this? Or is it meant to be cut at 45 degree angles to fill in the corner when it was installed. Just curious since we want to have our other shower remodeled at some point and hopefully something like this doesn’t come up.

That's some poor schluter joinery.  It looks like that is all on the outside of the shower. If so, the easiest thing to do is to buy or mix some caulk in a color to match the metal and fill the voids.

Just get some white Latex caulk from your home store and apply a few beads of it to fill in the areas and smooth/square it out and touch up with some matching paint.

White on the dark metal will stick out like that black grain of rice in the bag of white rice. better to get matching caulk or mix a little. It outside the shower, acrylic latex caulk is fine and mixes easy.

@RMDman  Ok, you got me on that one but the OP stated it wasn't noticeable so I was just giving a quick fix.  Looks like a bad patch already there too.

I doubt silicone caulk will take the paint well.

@Huesmann  Forgot to caulk check.. :-)
